# Writing number (var) into a .txt on FTP server with .ftplib with python

Tags: python, ftp, beautifulsoup, ftplib

I have a script, that puts a number (in this case "9") into a var and saves it as a .txt file. Now i wanted to store that number automatically in a .txt file on my FTP server.

connecting to FTP works and i managed to create the "lifetime_wins.txt" file.
But it has nothing in it.

I want to store the data of the "headers" variable in the txt.
can anyone help here? I am not that good at python :x

Code:

```
import bs4
import time


def main():

    #----INPUT BASIC----

    #import bs4 and url-grabbing-module
    from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
    from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

    #setting var "url" to the page
    url = 'https://fortnitetracker.com/profile/psn/Rehgum'

    #var req to uReq and setting Mozilla / decoding for https
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

    #decoding
    web_byte = urlopen(req).read()
    webpage = web_byte.decode('utf-8')
    urlopen(req).close()

    #html parsing
    page_soup = soup(webpage, "html.parser")

    #----SORTING----

    #selecting <div> lifetime
    lifetime = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "top-stats"})

    #headers and file creation
    filename = "lifetime_wins.txt"
    f = open(filename, "w")

    #setting lifetime into another var (0)
    stats = lifetime[0]

    #selecting container with the right information
    stats.div.div

    #setting variable to put in the value
    value = stats.div.div

    #----OUTPUT----
    output = value.text

    #----PRINTING OUTPUT----
    print("Lifetime Siege: " + output)
    headers = ("#" + output + " ")
    f.write(headers)
    f.close()

    #---FTP CONNECTION---
    from ftplib import FTP  
    ftp = FTP('server.1and1-data.host')
    ftp.login('user','pw')
    ftp.cwd('/')


    #--WRITING HEADERS TO TXT ON FTP--

    def placeFile():
        filename = 'lifetime_wins.txt'
        ftp.storbinary('STOR '+filename, f.write(headers), open(filename, 'rb'))
        f.close()
        ftp.quit()

    #---------------------------------


#loop
    time.sleep(30)
    main()


for i in range(1, 2):
    main()

while i < 1:
    print("Ende")
```

Edit:

Its working after changing the method from storing a var into the text to storing the file first and then upload it. 
Post was not a duplicate, as i don't wanted to upload a file but changing some content of a file...

Working Code:

```
import bs4
import time
import ftplib

def main():

    #----INPUT BASIC----

    #import bs4 and url-grabbing-module
    from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
    from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

    #setting var "url" to the page
    url = 'https://fortnitetracker.com/profile/psn/Rehgum'

    #var req to uReq and setting Mozilla / decoding for https
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

    #decoding
    web_byte = urlopen(req).read()
    webpage = web_byte.decode('utf-8')
    urlopen(req).close()

    #html parsing
    page_soup = soup(webpage, "html.parser")

    #----SORTING----

    #selecting <div> lifetime
    lifetime = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "top-stats"})

    #headers and file creation
    filename = "lifetime_wins.txt"
    f = open(filename, "w")

    #setting lifetime into another var (0)
    stats = lifetime[0]

    #selecting container with the right information
    stats.div.div

    #setting variable to put in the value
    value = stats.div.div

    #----OUTPUT----
    output = value.text

    #----PRINTING OUTPUT----
    print("Lifetime Siege: " + output)
    headers = ("#" + output + " ")
    f.write(headers)
    f.close()

    #---FTP CONNECTION---
    from ftplib import FTP  
    ftp = FTP('SERVER.1and1-data.host')
    ftp.login('USER','PW')
    ftp.cwd('/')

        #--UPLOADING TXT ON FTP--

    file = open('lifetime_wins.txt','rb')
    ftp.storbinary('STOR ' +"lifetime_wins.txt", file)
    file.close() 
    ftp.quit()


#loop
    time.sleep(30)
    main()


for i in range(1, 2):
    main()

while i < 1:
    print("Ende")
```

Comment: Your call to `ftp.storbinary` is just wrong. Check the linked question for correct parameters.

Comment: Thanks @MartinPrikryl .. i changed it and the method i am uploading the content from a value to a file... works now and its cool for me this way. i wanted to simplify the process, so that i don't have to store a file locally first, that is then uploaded... i wanted to store the value direcly on the (ftp generated) .txt file, thats why i don't see that post as a duplicate, but thanks for your help !

Comment: I've added other questions that show how to upload a contents from memory.

Comment: thanks again... posted the working code above :)